# Tracking performance of a stored procedure over time via Query Store - possible?

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on some queries, using the Query Store objects (query_store_runtime_stats, query_store_plan, query_store_query) that will track the performance of any stored procedure over time.

I have the following query to create the #RuntimeStats table:

```
Declare @LookbackDayCount int = 14
SELECT 
    ObjectName = ISNULL(Object_Name(q.object_id), 'None') 
    ,RunDate = convert(date, first_execution_time)
    ,Total_LogicalReads = ROUND(CONVERT(FLOAT, SUM(rs.avg_logical_io_reads * rs.count_executions)) * 8, 2) 
    ,Total_CPU = ROUND(CONVERT(FLOAT, SUM(rs.avg_cpu_time * rs.count_executions)) * 8, 2) 
    ,Total_Duration = ROUND(CONVERT(FLOAT, SUM(rs.avg_duration * rs.count_executions)) * 8, 2)
Into #RuntimeStats
FROM sys.query_store_runtime_stats rs
JOIN sys.query_store_plan p ON p.plan_id = rs.plan_id
JOIN sys.query_store_query q ON q.query_id = p.query_id
WHERE 
    rs.first_execution_time  between dateadd(dd, @LookbackDayCount * -1, getdate()) and getdate()
GROUP BY 
    ISNULL(Object_Name(q.object_id), '') 
    ,q.object_id
    ,convert(date, first_execution_time)
```

This query is not getting the data I expect. It only has what looks like a full set of object names for the most recent day. As you go back in time, it only retains the most highly used objects. So, this simple query:

```
Select RunDate, TotalObjects = count(ObjectName ) 
From #RuntimeStats 
Group by RunDate
Order by rundate desc
```

...returns data like this:

```
RunDate     Total
2021-07-28  796
2021-07-27  27
2021-07-26  27
2021-07-25  14
2021-07-24  14
2021-07-23  15
2021-07-22  15
2021-07-21  14
2021-07-20  14
2021-07-19  14
2021-07-18  13
```

In other words, it looks like it has a full set of data for the most recent day, but then loses older data, for almost all objects.

Any thoughts on what could be causing this? I don't care about the query text (any data from query_store_query_text), I just care about raw performance data (Logical Reads, CPU, etc) for the stored procedure.

Comment: What are your query store settings? it may be that you have the ```Size Based Cleanup Mode``` enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - yes I do. Looks like the answer may be to just increase the Max Size? If I were using a later version, (we're on 2017) looks like I could turn on the Custom data collection mode, and only collect that data which I want...